# Asymptotic of specific type of recurrence using Riemann integral approximation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

So I've seen this technique used before, but can't find where I saw it nor do I remember how to finish. The general idea was let's say you have a recurrence of the form
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{f(n)}{g(a_{n-1})}$$
Where $g$ is an increasing and positive function and $f$ is positive (it's usually something simple like the identity or constant). You want to compute an asymptotic for $a_n$. The idea is that you can rewrite it as
$$g(a_{n-1})(a_n-a_{n-1})=f(n)$$
And then sum from $n=1$ to $N$ to get
$$\sum_{n=1}^N g(a_{n-1})(a_n-a_{n-1})=\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$$
Now the LHS looks like a riemann sum, and since $g$ is increasing, we have that it is bounded above by $\int_{a_0}^{a_N} g(x)\, dx$. If $\frac{d}{dx} G(x)=g(x)$, we can say that
$$G(a_N)-G(a_0)\geq \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$$
$$G(a_N)\geq G(a_0)+\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$$
$$a_N\geq G^{-1}\left(G(a_0)+\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)\right)$$
And this gives a lower bound. But to make any conclusions about the asymptotics we would also need an upper bound and I am stuck there. We can't really use the same approach for the upperbound because we can't make it a right riemann sum.

I'm honestly just curious if anyone has a source for this type of approach or solutions that solve this type of problem this way as I can't remember where I initially saw this approach. But also if anyone knows how to solve it, that would of course also be appreciated

Comment: Do we have any assumptions about $f$ or is it just a function? I'd hope it is positive as otherwise the $a_n$ might not be increasing?

Comment: Oh yes, let's assume it is positive. I think usually in the cases I've seen it's something simple like the identity function.

Comment: In the second half of your question, $a_n$ should be $a_N$.

Comment: This is usually encountered as the Newton iteration scheme of finding solutions/roots to $f(a)=0$ where $g=f'$ is the first derivative, so $g$ is the integral of $f$, and $a_{n-1}$, $a_n$ are consecutive approximations.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar Interesting that the forms are similar, but the numerator in Newton's method would be $f(a_{n-1})$ as opposed to just $f(n)$.

Comment: I don't know if it is useful, but maybe try this: $g(a_{n-1})(a_n-a_{n-1}) = f(n)$, therefore $g(a_n)(a_n-a_{n-1}) = f(n)\frac{g(a_n)}{g(a_{n-1})}$ (assuming g is positive) which summing from $1$ to $N$ will be bounded below by the same integral you got, and we get $G(a_N)-G(a_0)\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{g(a_n)}{g(a_{n-1})}f(n)$

Comment: @Eric I think some of your signs are flipped, but I get the general idea. What does control mean in this sense?

Comment: If the differences obey $a_n-a_{n-1} \geq a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$, then we can estimate the left Riemann sum by a right Riemann sum on some other interval. This can yield a lower bound, if one can prove that the differences obey this property.